# How to filter column values with space in it in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.

```
 X_vegesum     X_bmi5cat
     53         Obese
     148     Underweight
     643    Normal weight
     167    Normal weight
```

In the second column, I have a value "Normal weight" which is having a space in it. Now when I try to filter out only "Normal weight" values using the following code, I get NULL answer.

```
data%>% filter(X_bmi5cat == 'Normal Weight')
```

I get 0 rows for this filtering. Perhaps, there is a space in 'Normal Weight'. It is working fine for other values with no space.

Comment: Nope! You were looking for upper-case `W` but your data shows lower-case. If you want case-insensitive, try either `tolower(X_bmi5cat) == "normal weight"` (make sure to down-case the comparison string), or look at regex options (not necessary here) such as `grepl("normal weight", X_bmi5cat, ignore.case=TRUE)`.

Comment: Though this isn't a cosmic question, @RonakShah, this is not a duplicate of `trimws`.

Comment: I tried the 'trimws' but it is not working.

Comment: @r2evans..This helped. Thanks

Comment: @r2evans yes, you are right. I was just blind. I have reopened the question but not sure if it should be a typo or duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842828/ignore-case-in-dplyr-package